# Grab specific text from XML

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

Hello :) This is my first python program but it doesn't work.

What I want to do :

- import a XML file and grab only Example.swf from

```py
<page id="Example">
<info>
<title>page 1</title>
</info>
<vector_file>Example.swf</vector_file>
</page>
(the text inside <vector_file>)
```

- than download the associated file on a website (https://website.com/.../.../Example.swf)
- than rename it 1.swf (or page 1.swf)
- and loop until I reach the last file, at the end of the page (Exampleaa_idontknow.swf → 231.swf)
- convert all the files in pdf

What i have done (but useless, because of AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'xpath'):

```py
import re
import urllib.request
import requests
import time
import requests
import lxml
import lxml.html
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

DIR="C:/Users/mypath.../"
for filename in os.listdir(DIR):
    if filename.endswith(".xml"):
        with open(file=DIR+".xml",mode='r',encoding='utf-8') as file:
            _tree = ET.fromstring(text=file.read())
            _all_metadata_tags = _tree.xpath('.//vector_file')
            for i in _all_metadata_tags:
                print(i.text + '\n')

    else:
        print("skipping for filename")
```

Comment: You can use `glob` to work with wildcards and get a list of matching files only: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to make up your mind about what module you're going to use. `lxml` or `xml`? Import only one of them. `lxml` has more features, but it's an external dependency. `xml` is more basic, but it is built-in. Both modules share a lot of their API, so they are easy to confuse. Check that you're looking at the correct documentation.

For what you want to do, the built-in module is good enough. However, the `.xpath()` method is not supported there, the method you are looking for here [is called `.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall).

Then you need to remember to **never parse XML files by opening them as plain text files**, reading them into into string, and parsing that string. Not only is this wasteful, it's fundamentally the wrong thing to do. XML parsers have built-in automatic encoding detection. This mechanism makes sure you never have to worry about file encodings, but you have to *use it*, too.

It's not only better, but less code to write: Use `ET.parse()` and pass a filename.

```
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

DIR = r'C:\Users\mypath'

for filename in os.listdir(DIR):
    if not filename.lower().endswith(".xml"):
        print("skipping for filename")
        continue

    fullname = os.path.join(DIR, filename)
    tree = ET.parse(fullname)

    for vector_file in tree.findall('.//vector_file'):
        print(vector_file.text + '\n')
```

If you only expect a single `<vector_file>` element per file, or if you only care for the first such element, use `.find()` instead of `.findall()`:

```
vector_file = tree.find('.//vector_file')

if vector_file is None:
    print('Nothing found')
else:
    print(vector_file.text + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but now i want to download them and rename each one by one (page1.swf, page2.swf, page3.swf) ? How can i do that ? Anyway thank you much

Comment: You do that by Googling *"how to rename files with Python"* :)